# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON In Client side when posting to backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, express

```
const handleAddItem = event =>{
    event.preventDefault()
    const item = {
        name: event.target.name.value,
        description: event.target.name.value,
        img: event.target.img,
        category: event.target.category.value,
        email: user.email,
        quantity: event.target.quantity.value,
        price: event.target.price.value,
        suppName: event.target.supplierName.value
    }
    console.log(item);
    axios.post('the Url', item)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        const {data} = response;
        if(data.insertedId){
            alert('User Added Successfully')
        event.target.reset();
        }
    })
```

This is my code and the qrror is shown when I try to post my array. Don't understand why happening. my backend is totally good.
the title of the error is

Comment: Can you post the value printed for console.log(item);

Comment: What is the title error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.